# Why does using Data in R ,having different results when using same in Python

Tags: python, r, port

There are different types of json inputs which needs to be transformed.

Inputs:

Sample#1:

```
{ "table_name": [{ "id": 1, "name": "john" },{ "id": 2, "name": "doe" }] }
```

Sample#2:

```
{
  "id": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  "name": [
    "john",
    "doe"
  ]
}
```

Desired JSON output for both objects:

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "john" },{ "id": 2, "name": "doe" }]
```

In R code this is done using `data <- tidyr::unnest(data)`. I have different ways in pyhton like `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient = "index").transpose()` and couple other variations but no luck.

Comment: Seems like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980830/unnest-dictionary-of-arrays-from-json. Did you create a new account?

Comment: Try: `data = pandas.DataFrame(data.get("table_name", data)).to_json(orient="records")` for either/both datasets.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict` is going to expect a Python `dict` object. You'll want to convert your JSON into a `dict` first if you want to use that.

### **Short Cut for Simpler Case**

For the simpler case (your sample 2) above we can actually skip the `dict` conversion entirely and use a pandas built in method to load JSON directly:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> json_data = StringIO('{"id": ["1","2"],"name": ["john","doe"]}')
>>> df = pd.read_json(json_data)
>>> df
   id  name
0   1  john
1   2   doe
```

For some reason loading A literal strings of JSON directly is deprecated and it needs to be wrapped in a `StringIO` object, as demonstrated above.

### **Using the `json` Module**

The first one, with the `table_name`, does cause a bit of an issue here, we end up with this result if we try it that way:

```
                  table_name
0  {'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}
1   {'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'}
```

which isn't ideal. We can work around this using the built-in `json` module to turn it into a proper Python `dict`:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json_dict = json.loads('{ "table_name": [{ "id": 1, "name": "john" },{ "id": 2, "name": "doe" }] }')
>>> json_dict
{'table_name': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'john'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'doe'}]}
```

We're not quite done however as this will still have the same problem, but now we've got it loaded in python-land we can resolve that easily if we know the table name:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["table_name"])
>>> df
   id  name
0   1  john
1   2   doe
```

### **Outputting to JSON**

pandas dataframes have a built-in `to_json` method, but by default it will be in the wrong format. To get what you have asked for, do this:

```py
>>> output = df.to_json(orient="records")
>>> output
'[{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":2,"name":"doe"}]'
```

`orient="records"` is [one of several ways](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) we can instruct pandas to format the resulting JSON, but this one in particular matches your example output.

You can then write that to a file or whatever you wanted to do with it.